# How to storage data for specific dates

Tags: java, android

I am writing an Android application in Java and have the following problems.

I want to store some data, that I log at different days in the week. And I want to show this data in a diagram for example, and to show me the data that has been logged to this date. My question is, what is the best method to solve this problem. Should I use an sqLite database or can I save my data in List? It should be fast and easy to handle when I use the data to show it in my statistics (f.e. diagram) or to filter for specific dates.

Comment: This question is vague. Specific recommendations cannot be made on so little information. You should clearly describe the business problem, as simply as possible. Give concrete examples of data. Give some idea of size of data, dozens of items, millions?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use some method that will be persistent across executions of your program, and of course a database will provide persistent storage. If you use a list, you'll have to save it to storage somehow (perhaps via serialising to a file).

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, should i use different tables for the days ?

Comment: @developKinberg Well I don't know enough about the data you want to store, but I suggest using a row for each day, all in one table.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too vague and lacking in detail to provide specific suggestion. But here are some rough ideas.

## Little data, simple data

For small amounts of data in simple lists that can fit into memory, write values to text files. I would use the [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library to assist with the chore of actually writing the files in [Comma-separated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) or [Tab-delimited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) formats.

## Little data, slightly complicated data

For storing slightly more complicated objects in a collection that can fit into memory, use the [Simple XML Serialization](http://simple.sourceforge.net) library.

## Much data, and/or very complicated data

If you have large amounts of data that do not fit comfortably into memory, or you have many interrelated lists that should be stored as related tables, use a relational database. [SQLite](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjU2ty6g_TMAhUB9WMKHfgjAwEQFggyMAc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSQLite&usg=AFQjCNEHMx6VrSfd8EqsjVBLxp57rS0uhA&sig2=fBXb2Vwoo8FwB904kmUsFQ&bvm=bv.122676328,d.cGc) is indeed very lite, intended as an alternative to writing to files, not intended to compete against full-fledged databases. For more serious database work, I suggest the [H2 Database Engine](http://www.h2database.com/), built in pure Java.

Be sure to learn about:

- [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes (especially [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) & [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html))
- [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answers above — and since you asked about it specifically — you should definitely consider `sqlite` over serializing your own file.

The [2013 PostgreSQL Conference Keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvmMzI0X7fE) presented some insightful statistics into the benefits of using sqlite over flat files. Sqlite is, according to its creator (who gave the keynote) "a replacement for fopen()" and uses a mature, familiar SQL API, so it would seem perfectly suited to your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately SQLite does not have defined data types, and has poor support for date-time. SQLite could be made to work. The original poster really did not give us enough information to make a clear recommendation.